# Is it possible to specify categories in point objects for column charts in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to specify column charts with objects for points. The reason for this is that I don't have to then split up the array of objects into separate arrays of categories and values.

I have tried the following, but neither works. (I'm interested in both specifying the category for columns, and specifying datetimes for x values.)

```
var data_1 = [
    {x:new Date('2013-01-03'),y:2},
    {x:new Date("2013-01-02"),y:6},
    {x:new Date("2013-01-01"),y:4},
];
var data_2 = [
    {category: "a", y: 3},
    {category: "b", y: 3},
    {category: "c", y: 4}
];
var create_chart = function(el, data){
    var init_obj = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'a',
            data: data
        }]
    };
    el.highcharts(init_obj);

};

create_chart($('#chart1'), data_1);
create_chart($('#chart2'), data_2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In highcharts configuration you can set onyl one type of one xAxis. If xAxis has datetime type, you cannot use categoires. Only wayt o common both types is use two xAxis with different types.

Comment: This is best answer here. I'm still confused as to how to categorise the data but without explicitly passing a categories array (I would much rather pass an array of objects in which I specify the category for each point).